# How does using 'this' in a simple jquery function work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am having trouble understanding this code:

```
$.functionone = function(){
  function setOptions(newOptions){
      ...
  }
  this.setOptions = setOptions;
}
```

what does adding 'this' in 'this.setOptions' for?  I understand that its referencing the function setOptions, but does adding the 'this' there make the function get called? I know this refers to the DOM element, but whats the point of having it in this particular scenario.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will simply *expose* the function from the scope of `functionone`, to be a property of the `$` object.

For example:

```
$.functionone = function(){

  function setOptions(newOptions){
    //...
  }
  this.setOptions = setOptions;
};

typeof $.setOptions; // "undefined", it doesn't exist
$.functionone();
typeof $.setOptions; // "function"
```

The `this` value on JavaScript is set implicitly when you make a function call.

If the function is bound as a property of an object (like `$.functionone`), the `this` value will refer to the *base object* (`$` in your example).

That's not so useful IMO, it's equivalent to:

```
$.functionone = function(){
  this.setOptions = function (newOptions) {
    //...
  };
};
```

Which is at the end, when you invoke `functionone`, equivalent to:

```
$.setOptions = function (newOptions) {
  //..
};
```

The difference is that the function is not named, which can be useful for debugging.

Working with the `this` value on jQuery plugins is more usual when you extend the `jQuery.fn` object, in that case the `this` value refers to the jQuery object that contains the matched elements, and not to the jQuery constructor itself.

Answer (score 1):

The code creates a function and adds it as a "setOptions" property of the DOM element.

Presumably, some other part of the code will know to look for a "setOptions" function on the DOM element and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the particular DOM element that called the function.

The following line:

```
this.setOptions = setOptions;
```

Means the function "setOptions" is assigned to the "setOptions" property of the DOM Element.